# C# MVC - Creating dynamic charts using datetimepickers

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm attempting to create a charting module in my site where clients can view their data. I originally created some pre-set charts (Annual, Monthly) to represent different aspects of my data, but now I'd like to change it so that the date window used to populate the chart is dynamically chosen by the user via two DateTimePickers.

My data:

```
public class visitItem
{

    public int VisitId { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public DateTime FirstSeen { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastSeen { get; set; }

    public double Duration { get; set; }

}
```

I have an Action Method in my controller:

```
public ActionResult dateGapDuration(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
        //Fetch client data
        visits = getList();

        //Cut down list to elements within interval.
        var Model = visits.Where(x => x.FirstSeen.Ticks > start.Ticks && x.FirstSeen.Ticks < end.Ticks).ToList<visitItem>();

        //My generic chart format initialiser.
        var chart1 = getChartSetup();
        chart1.Width = 1100;
        chart1.Height = 500;

        //Check Interval Length and apply relevant list grouping (i.e. to avoid displaying every day is interval is 4 years)
        if (interval < 60 * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay)
        {
             var chartList = Model.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(v => v.FirstSeen.Day)
            .Select(g => new visitItem
            {
                FirstSeen = DateTime.Parse(g.Key.ToString()),
                Duration = g.Sum(i => i.Duration)
            });
        }       

        //Cycle through chartList and populate data points.
        //Return image to view...

}
```

The chart is then returned as an image to be displayed.

I have previously being rendering my pre-set charts in a partial view which is then hidden/revealed using a button. Partial views looked generally like this for example:

```
<div id="annualdur" hidden="hidden">
<img src="@Url.Action("annualDuration", "Analytics", new { year = "2014" })" />
```

Now that I want the chart to be variable:

1. How would I call this function from the view? My understanding is that using a partial view for this would not recall the function when the datetimepickers values are changed and so I think I need another method of doing this.
2. Assuming a solution to 1. above, is it possible to hold the `DateTime` of a datetimepicker in the view to pass to the function on a `Load chart` style button press?

Comment: Use javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of the datepicker (or the `.click()` event of an 'update' button) and use ajax to call the controller method, passing the value of the datepickers, and in the success callback, update the DOM with a partial view (containing the image) returned by the method

Comment: Thanks for the comment...I understand how to use the .change() method after taking a look around, but calling the controller method with ajax and then appending the image to the view is something I don't know how to do. Could you advise maybe?

Comment: Oh! apologies it's only 3pm here. Thankyou, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to allow the user to select both the start and end dates before reloading the chart, I suggest including button element in the view

```
<button type="button" id="update-chart">Update</button>
// Place holder for the chart
<div id="chart"><div>
```

and assuming also that you have 2 inputs for the date pickers with ID's of `StartDate` and `EndDate`, you can use ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial view based on the dates

```
var chart = $('#chart);
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateChart", yourController)';
$('#update-chart).click(function() {
  var start = $('#StartDate').val();
  var end = $('#EndDate').val();
  chart.load(url, { startDate: start, endDate: end });
});
```

Then create a controller method to return a partial view containing the chart. Note I'm unsure exactly what you are doing since your `<img>` tag is calling the `annualDuration()` method, but you have shown a method named `dateGapDuration`, but my best guess is that you need a partial view (say `_Chart.cshtml`) containing

```
<img src="@Url.Action("dateGapDuration", "Analytics", new { start = ViewBag.StartDate, end = ViewBag.EndDate })" />
```

then the controller would be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateChart(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
  // Pass the dates to the partial view
  ViewBag.StartDate = startDate;
  ViewBag.EndDate = endDate;
  return PartialView("_Chart"); // rename to suit
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay so I render the partial view via an UpdateChart action method and this returns the image in a different page. How would I make it so the chart is appended to the current page? This was what confused me as I have been hiding and revealing partial views embedded into my master views, but if I do that in this case I'm only hiding/revealing and once rendered the dateGapDuration method won't be recalled will it?

Comment: That the function of the script and the ajax call. When you click the update button it makes an ajax call to the `UpdateChart()` method, passing the values of the selected dates, which in turn creates a partial view containing your image and then returns it to the page and inserts it into the `<div id="chart"><div>` (using the jquery `.load()` function). I'm not sure why your saying it returns the image in a different page? (ajax calls stay on the same page). Have you actually tried it?